# PHP 'use' what do this

Tags: php, namespaces

i know 'use' working with namespaces but it is including some class with namespace or i need to include this class too?

Example:

```
        namespace Some\Class;

        use Some\Foo; // in Foo class i have static someFunction()

        class MysqlAdapter
        {
            public static function connect()
            {
                Foo::someFunction(); // can i use this? or i need include Foo class?
                return $connect;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use` doesn't include classes. You need an autoloader if you want to automatically include class files:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Further, consider using an autoload managed service provider [such as composer!](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)